Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:detachedConfiguration4'. See the Console for details
Unity Version: 2022.3.39f1
Admob version: v9.2.0
Firebase Version: 12.1.0

Configure project :launcher
WARNING:The option setting 'android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false' is deprecated.
The current default is 'true'.
It will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (7.4.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 33
This warning can be suppressed by adding
android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties
The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34

Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues
Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease
Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractDeepLinksForAarRelease
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues
Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksForAarRelease
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareReleaseArtProfile
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:writeReleaseAarMetadata
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJavaResource


Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
package="com.google.unity.ads" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: D:\games\IOS\number ios\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.


Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders
Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish
Task :unityLibrary:prepareReleaseArtProfile
Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes
Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseAarMetadata
Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease
Task :unityLibrary:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJavaResource
Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses
Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
Task :launcher:checkReleaseAarMetadata
Task :launcher:mapReleaseSourceSetPaths
Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources
Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractReleaseAnnotations


Task :launcher:processReleaseMainManifest
[:googlemobileads-unity:] C:\Users\LENOVO.gradle\caches\transforms-3\1ac707f5653e1a7cb500d0b29675bd01\transformed\jetified-googlemobileads-unity\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.unity.ads' used in: :googlemobileads-unity:, :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib.


Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
Task :unityLibrary:extractReleaseAnnotations
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:syncReleaseLibJars
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:createFullJarRelease
Task :launcher:processReleaseManifestForPackage
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE


Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac


Task :launcher:compressReleaseAssets
Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
Task :launcher:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles
Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
Task :unityLibrary:syncReleaseLibJars
Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies
Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData
Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease
Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata
Task :launcher:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseArtProfile
Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
Task :unityLibrary:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
Task :unityLibrary:createFullJarRelease
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata
Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource


Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease


Task :launcher:optimizeReleaseResources


Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
WARNING:C:\Users\LENOVO.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0b750cf6153754fe4f7c32886e89b42d\transformed\jetified-analytics-7.0.0-runtime.jar: D8: Invalid stack map table at instruction 131: K7, error: Could not assign '[Initialized(java.util.regex.Pattern)]' to '[int]'. The stack value at index 0 (from top) with 'Initialized(java.util.regex.Pattern)' not being assignable to 'int'.
WARNING:C:\Users\LENOVO.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0b750cf6153754fe4f7c32886e89b42d\transformed\jetified-analytics-7.0.0-runtime.jar: D8: Invalid stack map table at instruction 53: K7, error: Could not assign '[Initialized(java.util.regex.Pattern)]' to '[int]'. The stack value at index 0 (from top) with 'Initialized(java.util.regex.Pattern)' not being assignable to 'int'.


Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease FAILED
94 actionable tasks: 94 executed

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Finally I resolved the issue by following these steps.
Enable custom base gradle template.
Build Setting>Publishing setting>custom base gradle template
Then open File
Assets>Plugins>Android>baseProjectTemplate.gradle
And change
id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false 

to
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false

